# Return Output of PowerShell to Bot Framework

Tags: c#, powershell, botframework

I'm currently running a powershell script to run disk clean-up within C#. I'm trying to return the output of the script and have the bot framework display it.

I already have a variable (ProcessLine) that should capture the output but not sure how to tell the bot framework to display it. The script is running just fine too.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using CoreTechChatbot.Dialogs.GuidedMenu.Resources;

namespace CoreTechChatbot.Dialogs.Shared
{

public class PowerShell

{
    public PowerShell()
    {
        var PSScript = @"DiskCleanUp.ps1";
        var RunPSScript = new ProcessStartInfo();
        var Process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file \"{PSScript}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            }
        };
        Process.Start();
        while (!Process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string ProcessLine = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
}
}
```

I expect the bot to capture and display the powershell script output

Comment: How are you passing the information to the bot?

Comment: The information should be captured within the string "ProcessLine" but I can't get the bot to display it.

Comment: You're using a relative path to the script file - have you verified that its directory is the current one and that PowerShell runs from it?

Comment: Yes, the file path is correct. I was able to verify that PS runs from the path

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding the design/layout of what you have going on. The above code is code that runs locally on some machine or server, or runs _within_ a bot? If the former; is your bot already created and setup with basic functionality?

Comment: The above code runs within the bot. Yes, the bot is already created and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the SendActivityAsync method. Please see [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). In this, you can send your output as text. There are other options you can use as well, such as a Adaptive Card or Hero Card (say perhaps you wanted to show a chart).

Please check out the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) for more information on how to implement [such things](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards).